# Is there a faster way of inserting data into an AoSoA at specific locations?

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics

Currently experiment with SoA AoSoA, kinda new to it so wanted to learn more about it through some simple projects.

The basic AoSoA layout looks like this.

```
struct Entity_4i {
    std::array<int32_t, 4> entityID;
};

std::vector<Entity_4i> Entities;
```

The way I have it now is that once I insert a value in say Entities[0][2] I would have to check if the last array in Entities has any free space. If there is I copy the old value at Entities[0][2] one index up. I then repeat this process for how many elements exist in the AoSoA. This sort of works but would most likely become very slow the bigger the AoSoA becomes. I would also have to allocate a new array if there is no space left which also would add latency to the current method.

Is there a better way of shuffling the elements to the right from a specific index for an AoSoA?

Comment: I may not understand what you plan to do, but SIMD will not help much, if you get input data one element at a time.

Comment: I've seen examples of people utilizing SoA for players where each array corresponds to data like x/y cords, health, entityID etc. In SoA if you wanted to add a new player to a specific index you could simply do vector.insert(). The problem is doing that in AoSoA.


The reason why I would like to insert new data into specific indexes is because the entityID is sorted. I've seen some other examples where people sorted using SIMD but was curious if there maybe was an easier of approaching this issue.

Comment: "In SoA if you wanted to add a new player to a specific index you could simply do vector.insert().": Do you mean in AoS (Array of Structures)? In SoA, you'd need to do separate inserts for each element. As said before, this is probably not the best way to utilize SIMD. Maybe just collect your data in an AoS and convert it to SoA or AoSoA at some point.